# Python selenium (html) checkbox

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, automation

I tried clicking this button using normal `.click()` command but it doesn't work

and after clicking it manually the class changes from this "`glyphsSpriteCircle__outline__24__grey_2 u-__7`" to this "`glyphsSpriteCircle_check__filled__24__blue_5 u-__7`" what to do?

```html
<button class="dCJp8">
  <span aria-label="Toggle selection" class="glyphsSpriteCircle__outline__24__grey_2 u-__7"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: can you please give more details:
1. what exactly did you try (minimum reproducible example)?
2. what happen? what does not work?

Comment: I am trying to automate a task for that I needed it to select a search bar and search a name after searching the name click on the checkbox to confirm it everything works great till the searching the name part but as soon as it comes to clicking the checkbox to select the name it gives me an error I am using .click function to click the button

Comment: why not use the button class 'dCJp8' 
driver.find_element_by_class_name('dCJp8').click()
?

Answer (score 0):

You have a dynamic element.

You need to use part that is not changing like :

or you can use regular expresions for part that is static like e.g

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'glyphsSpriteCircle')]")

see mor on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-xpath-in-selenium-with-python